# Change image object on template using Brother print Android SDK

Tags: java, android, printing, sdk

I have set up label printing from our app using the **b-PAC Android SDK (Java)**. Using the code below I can replace the text from my template with what I want.

```
// Start creating P-touch Template command print data
Boolean val= myPrinter.startPTTPrint(6, null);
Log.i("print", "startPTTPrint "+val);

// Replace text
myPrinter.replaceText("abcde");

// Trasmit P-touch Template command print data
PrinterStatus status=myPrinter.flushPTTPrint();
```

I am now trying to replace an image object within the template. I know it can be done in VBScript using:

```
bpac.Object ob = doc.GetObject("Photo");
ob.SetData(0, @"C:\Photo\635466380534236711.png", 4);
```

I can't find any Java examples of this within the b-PAC 3.1 SDK help guide and I have only just began coding in Java so I am very much a novice.

**Does anyone have experience with the Brother SDK/Java who can point me in the right direction?**

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this if anyone has managed it

Comment: I'm looking for the same. Any leads on this?

Comment: I am looking for the same. Any leads guys?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working
Basically I have a template that I copy to an new file on which I make the changes
The image object in the template is called imgPart, the other objects are textblocks

```
Dim m_partNum As String = "12345"
Dim m_PartName As String = "Plate Special 1 x 2" & vbCrLf & "4 Studs"
Dim m_PartImage As String = "c:\Danny\myLego\Labels\PartImages\3033.png"
Dim m_template As String = "c:\Danny\myLego\Templates\PRINTME.lbx"
Dim m_target As String = "c:\Danny\myLego\Templates\" & m_partNum & ".lbx"
Dim doc As bpac.DocumentClass = New bpac.DocumentClass
Try
   File.Copy(m_template, m_target, vbTrue)
   If doc.Open(m_target) <> False Then
      doc.GetObject("imgPart").SetData(0, m_PartImage, 4)
      doc.GetObject("txtPartName").Text = m_PartName
      doc.GetObject("txtPartNum").Text = m_partNum
      doc.Save()
      doc.Close()
         Else
          MsgBox("Open Error on Receipt with error")
   End If
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox("Error occurred :  " & ex.ToString)
End Try
```